# C - Parsing an input file into lines and characters

Tags: c, parsing, input

I am trying to write a C program to parse an input file so that individual lines are parsed, and in each line, the individual characters are then parsed further and stored in different variables in a `struct`. Here is my code so far (I have managed to parse individual characters without considering which line they are on):

```
/* create struct instances */
/* file open code */
...
int currentChar = fscanf(fp, "%s", storageArray);
while (currentChar != EOF) {
    printf("%s\n", storageArray);
    currentChar = fscanf(fp, "%s", storageArray);
}
...
/* file close code */
```

How can I adapt my code so that, instead of having each individual character print to the screen, I get behaviour like the following: (Note: in my program I assume the user input will have three characters to a line.)

```
INPUT FILE:
a b c
f e d

LINE STRUCT 1:
char1 = a
char2 = b
char3 = c
LINE STRUCT 2:
char1 = f
char2 = e
char3 = d
```

I feel like the solution might involve nested loops similar to the `while` I have written, where the outer one keeps track of lines and the inner one keeps track of characters.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define READ_OPTIONS "r"

struct line {
    char char1;
    char char2;
    char char3;

    struct line* next;
};

struct line* g_lines = NULL;


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char buf[8] = {0};
    struct line* newline, *iter, *head;
    int counter = 1;

    FILE* fp = fopen("file.txt", READ_OPTIONS);

    if(NULL != fp) {
        while(fgets(buf, 8, fp)) {
            newline = malloc(sizeof(struct line));
            if(NULL != newline) {
                memset(newline, 0, sizeof(struct line));
                sscanf(buf, "%c %c %c",
                    &newline->char1,
                    &newline->char2,
                    &newline->char3);

                if(NULL != g_lines) {
                    for(iter = g_lines;
                        NULL != iter->next;
                        iter = iter->next);

                    iter->next = newline;

                } else g_lines = newline;   
            }
        }
        fclose(fp);
    } else return -1;


    /* print the contents */
    for(iter = g_lines;
        NULL != iter;
        iter = iter->next, 
        ++counter)
        printf("Line %d: char1=%c char2=%c char3=%c\n",
                counter, iter->char1, iter->char2, 
                iter->char3);


    /* 
        now to free memory before returning
        control to the operating system
    */
    for(iter = g_lines;
        NULL != iter;)
    {
        head = iter->next;
        free(iter);
        iter = head;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
int i=1,j-1;    
printf("Line  STRUCT 1: ");
while( ( ch = fgetc(fp) ) != EOF ){
   if(ch=='\n'){
   printf("Line STRUCT %d \n",++i);
   j=1;
   }

  printf("Char %d  = %c \n",ch,j++);

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I wasn't looking to print "char %d" outright... I want to store these characters in variables that are part of the struct "Line". (i.e. store the first character in the variable "char1" in "Line", etc.)

Comment: you know how many character in one particular line is this predefine

Comment: Yes, the number of characters per line is predefined. There are three characters to a line, and for each "Line" struct I create, I would like to place these three characters in the struct variables char1, char2, char3 respectively.

Comment: you can also use char array instead of char variable

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
for (int i=0; !feof(fp); i++)
    fscanf(fp,"%c %c %c ",
        &storageArray[i].char1,
        &storageArray[i].char2,
        &storageArray[i].char3);
```